# Don't want to tap twice to share message in Facebook using sharekit app?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sharekit

I sharing message in **Facebook** by integrating **sharekit** in my iPhone application.I have written the method `facebookButtonPressed` which I am calling on tapping one button.
First time when facebook screen is appearing its asking for authentication in Facebook . I have given userid and password of my Facebook existing account and tapped for login. Now the facebook authentication screen disappeared.Now again I tapped the button to call the methoed `facebookButtonPressed`,then I got the message sharing screen.
I don't want to tap twice to get the message sharing screen.If any one has already solved this issue please help me.

```
-(void)facebookButtonPressed{
    NSString* body = @"test body";
    SHKSharer *fb = [[SHKFacebook alloc] init];
    SHKItem *item = [[SHKItem alloc] init];
    item.shareType = SHKShareTypeText;
    item.text = [body length]>140?[body substringToIndex:139]:body;
    fb.item = item;
    if(![fb isAuthorized])
    [fb authorize];
    [fb tryToSend];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, there will be action sheet to select how to share,you need to select Facebook.

```
NSString* body = @"test body";
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:body];
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item]; 
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the following:

```
item.shareType = SHKShareTypeText;
item.text = [body length]>140?[body substringToIndex:139]:body;
fb.item = item;
```

behind `[fb tryToSend];`

So that you first check whether fb is authorized and then share. Hope it helps.